# how to convert a string with floats numbers to another data type?

Tags: python, type-conversion

the string will be the price of some product, so it will basically come like this '1,433.10', the problem is that I need to compare it with the value that the user enters in an input that is only possible to enter integers because of the isdigit() method , used to check if the input is a number, and this causes the comparison to fail.
I already tried converting to int, to float and nothing worked, it only generated exceptions

```
def convert_values():
        price = results['price'][2:] # here is where the string with the value is, which in this case is '1,643.10'
        print(int(float(price))) # if I try to cast just to int: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,643.10'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before converting, replace the commas in the string with `''` as:

```
price = results['price'][2:].replace(',', '')
print(int(float(price)))
```

Comment: this worked, but i guess i will have to change the logic of checking the input. thanks anyway!!